# persist to database on an ajax request in symfony 3.4

Tags: ajax, symfony, request

i want to persist to database on an ajax request after a button click on twig 
this is the ajax part :

```
    <script>
        $('.btn').click( function(){
            var personnage = $(this).html()
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ url('ajax_route') }}",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    "personnage": personnage
                },
                async: true,
                success: function (data)
                {
                    console.log(data)
                    $( '#titre' ).text(data.titre);
                    $( '#producteur' ).text(data.producteur);
                }
            })
        });


    </script>
```

here i send some data 'personnage' to the controller action ,
 where i try to persist to  database , here is the controller part :

```
public function ajaxAction(Request $request)
 {
     public function ajaxAction(Request $request)
 {
     if (!$request->request->has('personnage')) {
         throw new BadRequestHttpException('personnage must be defined');
     }

     /* on récupère la valeur envoyée par la vue */
     $personnage = $request->request->get('personnage');
           //add to database
       $test = new test();
             $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
             $em->persist($test);
             $em->flush();
           //add to database
     return new JsonResponse([
         'titre' => 'ajax request received',
         'producteur' => 'Successfully',
     ]);
 }
 }
```

Note : when i remove the 'add to database' part the ajax request goes correctly and i get the response data ! but when i try to persist data to the db it throws an ajax error 500 :

1 AJAX request Method Type Status URL Time Profile POST xhr 500 http://localhost/myprojet/web/app_dev.php/ajax_request 1698ms 95ae4b

Comment: You can use the profiler, in debug mode for check errors ... maybe you throws a database exception.

Comment: yes i added the error log from the profiler please check it

Comment: Click on "95ae4b" and check the message